# SQL group by function error

Tags: mysql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am struggling this error for last 3 hours, but I cannot find the answers.

```
select store.store_num
       , Count(rental.rental_num)
       , Count(employee.emp_ID)
       , Avg(count(rental.rental_num))
from rental, employee, store
where rental.emp_ID = employee.emp_ID
and store.store_num = employee.store_num
and rental.rent_date >= ’01-JAN-14’
Group by store.store_num
```

It returns the error line number 4, says

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.
```

Would you please help me?

Comment: `Avg(count(rental.rental_num))` doesn't make sense in this context. - `count()` will return a single scalar per `grouping`, so the average would only have a sample of 1. Also, consider ANSI joins in lieu of where joins, and unless you may need to `count(distinct ..)` on the `rental_num` and `empID` unless you just need to exclude null counts. Finally, can we assume `Oracle` (not `mysql`) given the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining stores to rentals to employees.  Therefore your COUNT() functions will return the same value (the product of rentals and employees).

You haven't explained the logic of your homework, but let's take a wild guess: you want counts of the number of employees per store and the number of rentals per store, plus the average number of rentals across all stores.

In order to do this you need more than one query.  Here I have defined two sub-queries to get the base counts which I then join in the main query and use to derive the average.

```
with emps as (select store.store_num
                     , count(*) as cnt
              from employee, store
              where store.store_num = employee.store_num
              group by store.store_num)
     , rntls as (select employee.store_num
                     , count(*) as cnt
              from employee, rental
              where rental.emp_ID = employee.emp_ID
              and rental.rent_date >=  date '2014-01-01'
              group by employee.store_num)
select emps.store_num
       , rntl.cnt as rentals_count
       , emps.cnt as employees_count
       , avg(rntl.cnt) as rentals_avg
from emps
     , rntls
where rntls.store_num = emps.store_num
group by emps.store_num
       , rntl.cnt
       , emps.cnt
/
```

By the way, you should *always* include the century in any date strings: Y2K errors haven't gone away just because it's 2014.